# Split comma-separated string in T-SQL using Coalesce()?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I "googled" and found a magical and elegant sql query to split a comma-separated input string into rows in a single column.  Doing so allows a join instead of a "where in".  It used a `select into` or `insert into` combined with a `select`, `coalesce()` and `where` to create rows, one for each value in the string.

There are plenty of examples using `coalesce()` to form a string but none (any more) to split it.  I've also found this solution for the meantime:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

But I'm curious now, that I cannot "regoogle" for the gem I found before (about a year ago).

Has anyone seen how to split a string with `coalesce()`?  If so, how does its performance compare to the various sql string splitters that have been studied and compiled?

Comment: I believe the OP wants fn_Split()

Comment: You sure it wasn't CHARINDEX?

Answer (score 2):

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) simply returns the first non-null value from a group of expressions. It would not perform any magical splitting of a delimited string.

Comment: Actually, coalesce() was but one part of the magic.  I'm sure charindex was used also.